# ASP.NET MVC - navigating to the root of the site redirects me to Home/Index ONLY in Safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, safari

Whenever I navigate to the root of my MVC app:
[image]

Then press enter, and the URL redirects me to:
[image]

This **ONLY** happens in Safari.  I need for this behavior to **NOT** happen- what can I do to prevent this from happening?  Thanks!

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using?

Comment: What is configured to be your login page?  Is /Home/Index your default controller/action?

Comment: You say Safari is the only browser that does not work.  What browsers have you tried that do work?

Comment: @MattHouser - I tried IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: @MattHouser So basically, yes, that was correct- /Home/Index was configured as my LoginUrl in my web.config.  I removed it, then the app complained that it couldn't find login.aspx.  So, it appears it has a default login behavior...

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using?  Forms or Windows ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am not using any authentication at the moment.

Comment: And I do not have an Authentication mode deal in my web.config

Comment: Is anon access in IIS turned on ?

Comment: I don't get the feeling that it has to do with login. You might want to look at your default routes.MapRoute. When mvc can't find a mapping it returns the default controller (optionally the default action)